# Как поправить модальное окно?

Tags: javascript, html5

Привет всем. Подскажите, как поправить скрипт таким образом, чтобы при клике на "Оформить" выскакивало модальное окно, а при клике на "Завершить" в этом модальном окне спрашивало пользователя готов ли он закончить заказ.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$("#config").submit(function() {        
var send_form   = 1;        
var cpu         = $("#chosenmak").val();

$("#create_error").html("");
if (cpu == "") {
  $("#create_error").append("<div class='alert alert-block alert-error fade in' id='alert'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>Г—</button><h4 class='alert-heading'>Не выбран процессор</h4></div>"); 
  window.scrollTo(0, $("#alert").offset().top);
  send_form = 0; 
}                                                                                                
if (send_form == 1) { 
var valid = true; // определяете валидность полей
if (valid) {
$('#myModal').modal();
}
  temp = window.confirm('Собрать конфигурацию?'); 
  if (temp) 
  { return true; }
else { 
   return false; } 

  } else {

 return false;  

}   
return false;
});         
});
```

[JsFiddle(html code](http://jsfiddle.net/wmcbk993/3/)
Сейчас сначала спрашивает или готов клиент собрать конфиг, только при нажатии на "Отмена" показывается модальное

Comment: Кнопка "оформить" является кнопкой, по которой должно выскочить окно модальное окно, в котором нужно ввести данные(почту и имя клиента). После чего нажать на "Submit" и скрипт будет спрашивать "Вы уверены?".

Comment: Можно уже смотреть. Я поправил всё, чтобы показать как должно быть. Спрашивать про "Собрать конфигурацию?" должно после того, как появится модальное окно и пользователь нажмет на "Submit"

Comment: Что-то [вроде этого](http://jsfiddle.net/wmcbk993/5/)?

Comment: Да! Точно то, что надо было. Спасибо большое! Как вам поставить + 1 к репутации?)

Comment: На здоровье. Достаточно просто: сейчас я оформлю этот код как ответ на вопрос, и можно будет его принять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идея состоит в том, что по нажатию на кнопку "Оформить заказ" отображается только модальное окно (если был выбран вариант в `#chosenmak`), а по нажатию на кнопку "Submit" в модальном окне происходил вызов `window.confirm()`, на основании результата которого выбирается, отсылать форму или нет.

Переделанный JS код:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("button[name='korz']").on('click', function()
    {
        var cpu = $("#chosenmak").val();
        if (cpu == "")
        {
            $("#create_error").html("<div class='alert alert-block alert-error fade in' id='alert'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>Г—</button><h4 class='alert-heading'>Не выбран процессор</h4></div>");
            window.scrollTo(0, $("#alert").offset().top);
        }
        else
        {
            $("#create_error").html("");
            $('#myModal').modal();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $('#myModal .btn').on('click', function() 
    {
        return window.confirm('Собрать конфигурацию?');
    });
});
```

[Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmcbk993/5/).